# structure:breadcrumb Not working

Tags: structure, url-title, links, freebie

Im trying to add breadcrumbs to my application, Although I am not getting any results. Below you can see my code and a image of the result i am getting :(

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li class="home">
    <a href="/">
      <span class="pictos home-icon" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="H"></span> Home
        </a> 
    <span class="pictos smallArrow" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="P"></span>
      </li>
     {exp:structure:breadcrumb here_as_title="yes" wrap_each="li" inc_separator="yes" separator=" <span class='smallArrow' aria-hidden='true' data-icon='P'></span>" inc_home="no" add_last_class="yes" class="active"}
     {/exp:structure:breadcrumb}    
     {if freebie_1 == "search"}<li class="last">Search Results</li>{/if}
   </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All code works. Issue is resolved. The url wasnt being recognised as I was forcing the path